# Moving to mysqli, mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am converting my project from mysql to mysqli and my problem is that `mysqli_result()` does not work with my old code. My old code is: `mysql_result($res,0,0);`

When I try adding `mysqli_result()` with my old code it will not work.

Is there another way that'll work with my old parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysqli_result()` will not work with your old parameters so you need to create a new function, Here is the code for a function that'll work with your old prameters:

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```